# unable to redirect back to origin after signIn with google provider from next-auth/react although i am getting response from google

Tags: session, next-auth

I am trying to login using the provider (i.e.: google in my case) using next-auth/react.
I am using next 13.4.4 as my project. Although I am getting all the necessary response from   google provider and also sending the data to db (mongodb), i am getting this error where my session is always being undefined.

here are some screenshot of my issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM4al.png)

here the code for my NextAuthConfig

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlAXn.png)

Here i have provided a Provider that wraps all the children.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YigEq.png)

this is Provider Wrapper where I have used SessionProvider
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kTor.png)

I would be really happy to get some help here.

i want to be redirected back to my main origin url after a success from the next-auth/react.